# how does jetty clean up sockets in CLOSE_WAIT?

Tags: jetty

jetty version :  9.2.9.v20150224

One of our jetty boxes has the jetty process which reached the file description limit due to some other issue causing "no available jetty worker thread" several days back.
Majority of file descriptors are tcp sockets and now they are all in CLOSE_WAIT which means jetty hasn't been processing close request from a client.
It has been three days since jetty reached the file descriptor limit and we stopped sending any traffic to the jetty.  However, the number of CLOSE_WAIT sockets owned by the jetty are still same. FYI, all jetty worker threads are available now.

My question is about how jetty cleans up sockets closed by a client under heavy load environment.
1. In normal case, if a client sends "FIN" packet to jetty server, how does jetty clean up a connection? which module is processing that close event? Does jetty selector process a close event directly or pass it to jetty worker thread?

2.If acceptor fails to process new incoming request due to "Too many open files" as below, does jetty properly clean up an established tcp connection?

```
2017-08-26 01:51:07 [qtp1800890735-38-acceptor-3@77128dab-   ServerConnector@50de0926{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:4080}] WARN   o.e.jetty.server.ServerConnector - java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:241) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
```

3.We have the following low resource manager settings.

```
lowResources idleTimeout: 1000
lowResources maxConnections: 15000
```

The jetty currently has more than 20K sockets which are in CLOSE_WAIT. Why are these connections not cleaned up by jetty even after several days?

Thanks.

John

Comment: Might want to try a more recent version of Jetty 9.2, there's been LOTS of bug fixes and updates since Jetty 9.2.9 was released. Consider using `9.2.22.v20170606`.